# Web Audio: How to set different destination than speakers?

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

I struggle to understand how – using one AudioContext – I would achieve the following:

1. I use createMediaStreamSource to create the source of the context – works.
2. I then connect a volume node to the source – works.
3. I then want to create TWO outputs: One is the "standard" output (the speakers) and the second would be used to feed into a mediaRecorder

I struggle with the 3rd point. How do I specify a different output than speakers? Is the output still a stream I can feed into MediaRecorder?

Answer (score 4):

From what you describe, I assume that you have some code that looks like this:

```
mediaStreamAudioSourceNode
    .connect(gainNode) // your volume node
    .connect(audioContext.destination);
```

You just need to add another `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` and use that as an additional output.

```
const mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(audioContext);

gainNode.connect(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode);

const mediaRecoder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream);
```

Comment: It's *that* simple? I will try that!

Comment: Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination#examples